# intelij idea shortcut to implement interface as a new class

Tags: intellij-idea

suppose i have a interface like this:

```
public interface Dumb{
String getDumbName();
}
```

Is there any shortcut or menu in intellij-idea to create new classes implementing the interface with dummy implement methods like this:

```
 public class Dumber{
   public String getDumbName(){
return null;
}
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are multiple ways to go about this.

On the interface name itself, you can hit `Alt+Enter` (`Option+Enter` on Mac), then pick 'Implement interface'. IDEA will prompt for a class name and a package to put the new class in, then generate an implementation class.

Alternatively, create the class, then add `implements Dumb` after the name (`im<tab> Dumb`). IDEA will complain that your class doesn't implement the correct methods, and offer (`Alt+Enter Enter Enter`) to generate them for you. Hitting `Ctrl+I` or clicking 'Implement methods' in the Code menu also works.

Comment: i was looking for the ALternative (ALt+Enter..), thanks

Comment: By seeing this answer "On the interface name itself" I clicked Alt + Enter it showing different options so instead of "On the interface name itself" it should be written as **"You can visit the interface, click the interface name then press Alt+Enter"** _these lines are taken from jet brains community post page._